# Response message: Number of samples in transaction : 25, number of failing samples : 1

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I tried to send a https(GET) request on an e-commerce using 100 threads. In listeners tree, I got some error called "socket closed" even for HTTP response code 200 and moreover some request showing "No data to display". Why and when these two scenarios may  arise?

Scenario 1 - https://prnt.sc/y8twy0

Scenario 2 - https://prnt.sc/y8sj7f

Answer (score 0):

1. The error means that your test failed to download some image from [Amazon S3 storage](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and I don't really think that you should be downloading this type of assets because they **don't belong** to your  `priyoshop.com` domain. Hence I would recommend to exclude these entities living at S3 as well as any other 3rd-party images, banners, videos, etc. See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more details.

   If you still want to download external images but ignore the failures if any - set [`httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to `true`
2. With regards to this `No data to display` message it's absolutely normal because [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) don't send any requests, they act as "synthetic" samplers which report the sum the cumulative response times of their children therefore you need to click individual sampler to see its request data
3. And last but not the least, use GUI mode for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to load test execution it should be done in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. In the first statement you mentioned about downloading request though I requested GET that time. Can this error be appeared in GET request too?
https://prnt.sc/y8twy0

One more thing, I requested random thread request to server and got that response several time in the tree. Does the response indicate Transaction Controller? Because I didn't create any TC sampler for that testing.
https://prnt.sc/y8sj7f